# Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $|A|=\omega_1$. Prove $A$ does not embed into $\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $|A|=\omega_1$.

Prove $A$ does not embed into $\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$.

$\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$ is ordered with the lexicographic ordering.

I know that $A$ does not embed into $\omega_1$ since
otherwise $A$ and $\omega_1$ are isomorphic and $\omega_1$ embeds into $A$.
Then we can find a unique rational for each element in $\omega_1$, this is
an uncountable amount of unique rationals, which is a contradiction.

I don't know how to extend this proof that $A$ does not embed into $\omega_1$ into a proof that $A$
does not embed into $\mathbb{Q}\times\omega_1$.

Comment: What do you mean with embed? Just an injection? Must it preserve the order?

Comment: Yes, it is an order preserving injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Use the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is countable to show that if $f:A\to\Bbb Q\times\omega_1$ were an embedding, there would be a $q\in\Bbb Q$ such that $f[A]\cap(\{q\}\times\omega_1)$ was uncountable.